# Angular Material Table shows no rows until i click to sort or use pagination

Tags: angular, material-table

Im a bit baffled, im retrieving data from my Spring Boot back end to populate into an angular material table but for whatever reason the rows do not display until i use sorting or change pagination. I get the sense im missing something obvious, any help is appreciated.

datasource.ts

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { ParkingService } from 'src/app/services/parking.service';

// TODO: Replace this with your own data model type
export interface ParkingBuildingTableItem {
  building_name: string;
  postcode: string;
  owner_name: string;
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: ParkingBuildingTableItem[] = [
  //   { building_name: 'Rohanhaven', postcode: 'SA1 6BS', owner_name: 'Nikolaus, Buckridge and Marvin' },
  //   { building_name: 'Port Garfield', postcode: 'SA1 6BS', owner_name: 'MacGyver, Schneider and Bosco' },
  //   { building_name: 'Port Loveside', postcode: 'SA1 6BS', owner_name: 'Considine, Schimmel and Abernathy' },
];



/**
 * Data source for the ParkingBuildingTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class ParkingBuildingTableDataSource extends DataSource<ParkingBuildingTableItem> {
  data: ParkingBuildingTableItem[] = []
  paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  sort: MatSort | undefined;

  constructor(private parkingService: ParkingService) {
    super();
    this.parkingService.getBuildings().subscribe((x) => {
      this.data = x;
      console.log(this.data);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<ParkingBuildingTableItem[]> {
    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
      // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
      // stream for the data-table to consume.
      return merge(observableOf(this.data), this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange)
        .pipe(map(() => {
          return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
        }));
    } else {
      throw Error('Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.');
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect(): void { }

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: ParkingBuildingTableItem[]): ParkingBuildingTableItem[] {
    if (this.paginator) {
      const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: ParkingBuildingTableItem[]): ParkingBuildingTableItem[] {
    if (!this.sort || !this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort?.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort?.active) {
        case 'building_name': return compare(a.building_name, b.building_name, isAsc);
        case 'postcode': return compare(a.postcode, b.postcode, isAsc);
        case 'owner_name': return compare(a.owner_name, b.owner_name, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean): number {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ParkingBuildingTableDataSource, ParkingBuildingTableItem } from './parking-building-table-datasource';
import { ParkingService } from 'src/app/services/parking.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parking-building-table',
  templateUrl: './parking-building-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parking-building-table.component.scss']
})
export class ParkingBuildingTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<ParkingBuildingTableItem>;
  dataSource: ParkingBuildingTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['building_name', 'postcode', 'owner_name'];

  constructor(parkingService: ParkingService) {
    this.dataSource = new ParkingBuildingTableDataSource(parkingService);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 data-table">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Owner Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="owner_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Owner</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.owner_name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Postcode Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="postcode">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Postcode</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.postcode}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Building Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="building_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Building Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.building_name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="dataSource?.data?.length" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" aria-label="Select page">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Before i sort or change pagnation

[image]

After i sort or change pagnation

[image]

Snapshot of the console

[image]

Comment: Please provide the html. Have you ensured that this error is not appearing: `throw Error('Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.');` ? Perhaps put a `console.log()` here in case the component is catching this error silently.

Comment: if possible I also want the ./parking-building-table-datasource on top of the html

Comment: Ive added a screenshot of the console, its healthy and includes a console log of the array to be displayed, this log occurs within the datasource constructor so the data is there at initialisation no doubt, could this be an asyncronus operation issue? As in the view is being rendered before the data is available? I have ngAfterViewInit() in the component which as i understand it should take care of these issues, really lost. Ive included the HTML.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this issue? I'm having exactly the same problem... thanks.

Comment: I did indeed, the template for material tables is a bit misleading. I had to create an array stream and have the table component listen to changes on that stream so that each time a change was made the table updated. Essentially id copy the array add the new element if it was an add/remove operation then overwrite the array. Took a while to figure out. I can provide more detail if required.

Comment: @DanielHann more details required :)